# get permission denied when trying to k6 run a js file

Tags: javascript, permission-denied, k6

I am trying to learn `k6` and I started with [its official documents](https://docs.k6.io/docs). I tried the sample code in [run document](https://docs.k6.io/docs/running-k6) with both docker image and command-line. In the docker version it works fine:

```
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ docker run -i loadimpact/k6 run - <k6_test.js

      /\      |‾‾|  /‾‾/  /‾/   
     /\  /  \     |  |_/  /  / /    
    /  \/    \    |      |  /  ‾‾\  
   /          \   |  |‾\  \ | (_) | 
  / __________ \  |__|  \__\ \___/ .io

  execution: local--------------------------------------------------]   servertor
     output: -
     script: -

    duration: -, iterations: 1
     vus: 1, max: 1

time="2020-02-18T11:14:26Z" level=info msg=Running i=0 t=971.124809ms starting
...
time="2020-02-18T11:14:55Z" level=info msg=Running i=0 t=29.971104099s
time="2020-02-18T11:14:55Z" level=warning msg="Request Failed" error="Get http://test.loadimpact.com: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.168.14.109:1087: i/o timeout"
time="2020-02-18T11:14:56Z" level=info msg=Running i=0 t=30.971060995s
time="2020-02-18T11:14:56Z" level=info msg="Test finished" i=1 t=31.000143344s

    data_received..............: 0 B 0 B/s
    data_sent..................: 0 B 0 B/s
    http_req_blocked...........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_connecting........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_duration..........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_receiving.........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_sending...........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_tls_handshaking...: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_req_waiting...........: avg=0s  min=0s  med=0s  max=0s  p(90)=0s  p(95)=0s 
    http_reqs..................: 1   0.032258/s
    iteration_duration.........: avg=31s min=31s med=31s max=31s p(90)=31s p(95)=31s
    iterations.................: 1   0.032258/s
    vus........................: 1   min=1 max=1
    vus_max....................: 1   min=1 max=1
```

But when running from command-line, I get:

```
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ sudo k6 run ./k6_test.js

          /\      |‾‾|  /‾‾/  /‾/   
     /\  /  \     |  |_/  /  / /    
    /  \/    \    |      |  /  ‾‾\  
   /          \   |  |‾\  \ | (_) | 
  / __________ \  |__|  \__\ \___/ .io

ERRO[0000] open /home/zeinab/k6_test.js: permission denied
```

**EDIT 1:**

I get the same error when running with current user:

```
k6 run ./k6_test.js
```

**EDIT 2:**

I installed `k6` using `snap`:

```
zeinab@ZiZi:~$ snap install k6 
k6 v0.23.1 from Null Box (nullboxorg) installed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the fact you use snap to install it, this means that the k6 from inside snap doesn't have access to your whole fs as well (just as docker doesn't).

I don't understand snap all that much but given that whoever builds k6 for snap [hasn't updated](https://github.com/ipolyzos/k6-snap/blob/master/snap/snapcraft.yaml) it in the last year I would recommend just getting the [binary](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases) and running it ;).

Original answer:

It is exactly what it says: your `root` user can't open `/home/zeinab/k6_test.js` because they don't have permissions. I would guess they either can't read your home directory (`/home/zeinab`) or the file itself.

You don't really need to use `sudo` so either remove it or fix the permissions for the script, although again running with root is not necessary and is bad practice either way :D

As a side note, the docker works because whatever shell (probably bash) you run is the one that reads the file and send it to stdin of the docker process. So even if `docker` is alias for `sudo docker` it will still work.

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -l ./k6_test.js`

Comment: `-rw-r--r-- 1 zeinab zeinab 142 Feb 18 14:41 ./k6_test.js`

Comment: what about `ls -l /home/zeinab/k6_test.js` as well as does `cat /home/zeinab/k6_test.js` succeed?

Comment: It is `-rw-r--r-- 1 zeinab zeinab 142 Feb 18 14:41 /home/zeinab/k6_test.js` and yes, `cat /home/zeinab/k6_test.js` succeeds.

Comment: how did you install k6? what does `k6 version` says (not that should be relevant) ...

Comment: my gues this is apparmor/selinux ... with some strange way of installing k6. I don't think I have had problems with selinux so far but I also always build it from source or get the file from the [releases](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases) links ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208066/discussion-between-zeinab-abbasimazar-and--).

Comment: Did my final proposal both here and in the chat fix it ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had a lot to do lately. 
Yes, your last suggestion about not using the `snap` worked. Would you please add it to your answer, so I can mark it as approved.